# Loop the command continuously (without pausing) for "X" seconds

Tags: loops, batch-file

Currently I am working on a batch file to execute a command continuously for X no. of seconds, and after elapse of X, I wish to redirect it using `goto` function.

This is the closest I have got to what I intend the code to do.

```
:MainMenu
set yourno=
set /p yourno=Input your number:
set /p looptime=Input time:
goto PerformCalc

:PerformCalc
 set /a yourno= %yourno%+1
 timeout 1
 set /a looptime=%looptime%-1
 goto CheckLoop

:CheckLoop
if %looptime% equ 0 goto FinishScreen
goto PerformCalc

:FinishScreen
echo Congratulations Your no. is %yourno%
echo Operations completed in %looptime% seconds
pause
```

Now the problem with the above code is if I set the loop time for 10 seconds, it will perform only 10 operations. But that is not something I intend to do. I realize that I have inputted `timeout 1` in my code and reducing it by 1 everytime 1 second passes. However this is because I am unable to find a way to ***continuously*** loop the code for 10 seconds, without using timeout 1 thus pausing it to perform only 10 operations.

If you still do not get what I mean, here is the logical flow the code should perform (say for eg. the user inputs looptime as 10 seconds

```
For Time=10seconds
Do {set /a yourno= %yourno%+1 continuously}
After Time of 10 seconds has elapsed redirect to :FinishScreen
```

Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get end time
set seconds=10
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time: =0%") do set /A "endTime=1%%a%%b%%c%%d+seconds*100"

echo Start: %time%
echo Working %seconds% seconds, please wait...

set yourNo=0
:loop
set /A yourNo+=1

rem Check if end time had been reached
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%time: =0%") do if 1%%a%%b%%c%%d lss %endTime% goto loop

echo End:   %time%
echo This program could complete %yourNo% loops in 10 seconds
```

This method may fail if the processing time pass over midnight, but a simple adjustment can solve this point, if needed...

Comment: Hi. Although I found an alternative way to work the trick, I would like to thank you for your efforts.
Also could you explain what this does ?
`do set /A "endTime=1%%a%%b%%c%%d+seconds*100`